# В каких случаях используется описанная в примере реализация объявление класса

Tags: c++

Есть пример:

**sink.h**

```cpp
#include <QSharedPointer>

// объявление класса без реализации (для того, чтобы не подключать заголовок settings.h)
class Settings;

class Sink
{
public:

    // ...
    void setSettings(Settings* settings) noexcept;
    const Settings* settings() const noexcept;
    // ...

private:

    QSharedPointer<Settings> p_settings{ nullptr };
};
```

**settings.h**

```cpp
class Settings
{
public:

    // ...
    bool isValid() const noexcept;
    // ...
};
```

---

**sink.cpp**

```cpp
#include "sink.h"

// Подключение нашего заголовка для определения интерфейса класса
#include "settings.h"

void Sink::setSettings(Settings* settings) noexcept
{
    if (settings) {
        if (settings->isValid()) {
            p_settings.reset(settings);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Вопрос в том, в каких случаях можно объявить класс без его реализации (чтобы не подключать заголовок, как в нашем случае). Я правильно понимаю, что это возможно только тогда, когда этот класс является только частным и/или является указателем ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Архитектура важности, и порядка объявления кода :

1. Тип объекта - предварительно
2. Объявление статической переменной - предварительно
3. Объявление статической функции - предварительно
4. Структура объекта - фактическая
5. Инлайн функции - определение
6. Статические переменные - определение
7. Статические функции - определение

Ответ на вопрос : когда хватает предварительное объявление класса.

Когда не важен его размер. Этот код компилируется.

```
class Settings ;
// предварительно можно всё
extern Settings variable ;
Settings function ( Settings ) ;
class C {
  // только ссылку или указатель
  Settings * s ;
  // статическая переменная не хранится в объекте
  static  Settings ss ;
  // предварительно можно по значению
  Settings function ( Settings ) ;
} ;
// только ссылку или указатель
inline Settings & funci ( Settings * s ) {
  return * s ; }
Settings * pointer ;
Settings * funcs ( Settings & s ) {
  return & s ; }
```